# powershell ConvertTo-Html add class

Tags: html, css, class, powershell

My script is pulling information from server, than it converts to HTML and send the report by email.
Snippet:

```
$sourceFile = "log.log"
$targetFile = "log.html"
$file = Get-Content $sourceFile
$fileLine = @()
foreach ($Line in $file) {
  $MyObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
  Add-Member -InputObject $MyObject -Type NoteProperty -Name Load -Value $Line
  $fileLine += $MyObject
}
$fileLine | ConvertTo-Html -Property Load -head '<style> .tdclass{color:red;} </style>' | Out-File $target
```

Current HTML report snippet:

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Load on servers</th></tr>
<tr><td>Server1 load is 2442</td></tr>
<tr><td>Server2 load is 6126</td></tr>
<tr><td>Server3 load is 6443</td></tr>
<tr><td> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Higher than 4000:</td></tr>
<tr><td>6126</td></tr>
<tr><td>6443</td></tr>
</table>
```

This will generate an HTML report containing a table with tr and td.
Is there any method to make it generate **td with classes**, so I can insert the class name into the -head property with styles and make it red for the Higher than 4000: tds ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do it off the top of my head, but instead of piping to an out file, you'll want to store the output of `ConvertTo-HTML` in a variable.  Then you'll want to query the property by tag name (`td`) and select the one with inner text that's like "*higher*" and add the class name to the outer html.

Comment: `$out.ParsedHTML.getElementsByTagName("td") | (Where { $_.innerText -like "Higher" }).outerHTML` but I'm not sure how to change that value.

Comment: Bryce McDonald , this could be useful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is in a old post, but stumbled cross it looking to do something similar.
I was able to add CSS styling by doing a replace.
Here is an example:

```
$Report = $Report -replace '<td>PASS</td>','<td class="GreenStatus">PASS    &#10004;</td>'
```

You can then output $report to a file as normal, with the relevant css code in the header.
You would need some additional logic to find values over 4000

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Get-Help ConvertTo-Html` command you will get all parameters for the `ConvertTo-Html` command. Below is output:

```
ConvertTo-Html [[-Property] <Object[]>] [[-Head] <String[]>] [[-Title] <String>] [[-Body] <String[]>] [-As<String>] [-CssUri <Uri>] [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-PostContent <String[]>] [-PreContent <String[]>][<CommonParameters>]
```

You can create an external CSS file and give the CSS file path in the `[-CssUri]` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this will not solve my problem, since the HTML code will be with no class attributes. I need powershell to generate HTML with classes, so I can style them in the css file. I only need to make the color red for the <td> below "Higher than 4000".

Comment: Thanks @theIncorrigible1

Comment: @cata to apply CCS in your HTML classes is one way , you also use elements. if you need help in this  check in this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: @cata The conversion function can take .NET objects and apply whatever headers you want to them, then utilize CSS with that to apply style.